# Doing Traceroute/Troubleshoot within an ISP maybe using CGN?

Tags: networking, isp

**RFC 6598** states that 100.64.0.0/10 is an shared address space and can be only used when service provider router is capable of doing NAT across router interfaces when the addresses are identical on two different interfaces. Also it is not globally routable address space.

I have a friend of mine and his ISP uses (**RFC 1918**) as their CGN ip range or i am not sure if it is really CGN? Must be a routing technique i think. I did not see anything that uses address 100.64.0.0/10 other than my ISP before (me using DSL at that time) and now i have migrated into fiber optic and got public dynamic IP.

Reminder: doing tracert in mine still shows dsl.x.x.x.x just ignore that.

Now here where things get interesting... I used my own logic and performed a comparison between his isp and my isp.

In his side i performed a traceroute in his public ip that showed in whatismyip.
1 - 192.168.18.1
2 - 10.104.0.1
3 - 172.31.77.17
4 - 103.91.x.x
Starting in the 5th hop it goes into a blackhole
5 - RTO
6 - RTO
etc

Now in my side i have a public dynamic ip.

1 - dsl.49.x.x.51
2 - dsl.49.x.x.51

Then another traceroute in his side in my public dynamic ip 49.x.x.51
1 - 192.168.18.1
2 - 10.104.0.1
3 - 172.31.77.17
4 - 103.91.x.x
Starting in the 5th i get another private IP
5 - 10.1.0.14
6 - 10.1.0.13
In the 7th hop i got back to the public ip of 103.91.x.x
7 - 103.91.x.x
8-12 - my ISP server's
13 - dsl.49.x.x.51

Then another traceroute in my side doing traceroute in 103.91.x.x
I found out there was actually a hidden route.
1 - 192.168.1.1
2 - dsl.49.x.x.1 - My public ip block
3 - 122.x.x.x - My ISP
4 - 210.x.x.x - My ISP
5 - 210.x.x.x - My ISP
6 - atlas.cogentco.com 38.88.x.x
7 - atlas.cogentco.com 154.54.x.x
8 - ips.demarc.cogentco.com 154.18.x.x
9 - 45.201.x.x
10 - 103.91.x.x

It is a very interesting one. Anyone have ideas with this?

Edit: I also did not refer that sometimes he gets random high latency during peak hours and pinging to 8.8.8.8 shows a recurrence of rto during that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In his side i performed a traceroute in his public ip that showed in whatismyip. 1 - 192.168.18.1 2 - 10.104.0.1 3 - 172.31.77.17 4 - 103.91.x.x Starting in the 5th hop it goes into a blackhole 5 - RTO 6 - RTO etc

So you get the ISP internal hops, and as soon as you get to the 100.64.0.0/10 that connects your ISP either to another part of the ISP, or to some other ISP, traceroute stops working as expecting, as past the 100.64.0.0/10 the assumptions that make traceroute work don't hold any longer.

> Then another traceroute in my side doing traceroute in 103.91.x.x

I am surprised you got any results for this in the first place. The address is not globally routable, so whatever answers you get are artifacts of the state of CGN that is corrently going on somewhere in the Internet. It doesn't even have to be related to your friends ISP.

On other words, none of the results you got are surprising, and none says anything about what your friend's ISP actually does. Because the tools you have are not enough to "peek inside".

Comment: But we got an idea right? You said that "So you get the ISP internal hops, and as soon as you get to the 100.64.0.0/10 that connects your ISP either to another part of the ISP, or to some other ISP, traceroute stops working as expecting, as past the 100.64.0.0/10 the assumptions that make traceroute work don't hold any longer." then his isp must be using CGN. I also did not refer that sometimes he gets random high latency during peak hours and pinging to 8.8.8.8 shows a recurrence of rto during that time.

Comment: The 100.64.0.0/10 can be used for internal connections from on ISP to another (or from one ISP to CPE). Which means, yes, they do *something* across the connected devices - but maybe that is already a tier 3 provider with an internal routing schema that has nothing to do with the internet as it is described through RFCs. Not sure if you want to call this CGN or not, but that's mostly a matter of definition.